# i cant bake save or bake udim textures

Tags: texturing

I want to save udim tiles textures and bake but it doesnt allow me. Here an example:

[[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should create all the UDIM tiles first. And seems like currently (2.91.0) Blender can't bake all UDIMs at once, but you can try this addon https://github.com/anfeo/blender_addon_bake_UDIM